Higher Timeframe Indicators in KDB
Say I have ohlcv data on the 15min timescale, but I'm interested in obtaining an arbitrary indicator defined e.g.,
someind:{[n;close;...] mavg[n; close]};

on a daily timeframe? Of course, I could obtain a daily aggregation of bars, calculate the indicators and lj on dates to get the indicator on the lower timeframe.
However, all but the last values for the sma101D indicator below are premature (i.e., have a look-ahead bias). They need to be calcuated afresh. How can i do this efficiently in kdb+ for an arbitrary technical indicator ti[params...;o;h;l;c;v] given the availability of open, high, low, close, volume data on the lower (15m) timeframe?
Complicating matters a bit is that one has odd days in which the trading session is shorter than usual having therefore a smaller number of bars.
ticker date   sourcetime                    open   close  high   low    volume exchange ind101D
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM 2024.06.20 2024.06.20D08:45:00.000000000 980    980    981    979.55 119869 12       0.588969  / not ok
IBM 2024.06.20 2024.06.20D09:00:00.000000000 980    979.95 980.4  978.4  109497 12       0.588969  / not ok
IBM 2024.06.20 2024.06.20D09:15:00.000000000 979.55 978.85 979.95 978.2  142514 12       0.588969  / not ok
IBM 2024.06.20 2024.06.20D09:30:00.000000000 978.85 978.65 979.8  977.5  521472 12       0.588969  / not ok
IBM 2024.06.20 2024.06.20D09:45:00.000000000 978.75 979.1  979.9  977    619798 12       0.588969  / OK


You're saying that the 0.588969 value can't be known until the data at 09:45 so it shouldn't be filled into the previous rows. How is the 0.588989 number being arrived at? Why is it being filled into the earlier rows?

@terrylynch that's correct. The data above is obtained by aggregating the original ohlcv by date, calculating the indicator on those daily bars and then ohlcv lj dailybars after keying ohlcv by date. Of course, I can walk row by row of the original ohlcv, aggregate to daily bars upto that bar and keep the last bar to get the intended result but that's too slow and perhaps un-kdb like given it has an (p)each over each row of the ohlcv. So I was wondering if something more terse and efficient is possible.

If you were using only daily indicators and wanted them to display previous values until the next available datapoint then you'd calculate the daily indicator in a separate table use an asof join rather than a left join
q)t:([]ticker:`g#`IBM`MSFT where 3 3;sourcetime:6#2024.06.18D09:45 2024.06.19D09:45 2024.06.20D09:45;ind101D:1+til 6);
q)aj[`ticker`sourcetime;([]ticker:5#`IBM;sourcetime:2024.06.20D08:45+0D00:15*til 5);t]
ticker sourcetime                    ind101D
--------------------------------------------
IBM    2024.06.20D08:45:00.000000000 2
IBM    2024.06.20D09:00:00.000000000 2
IBM    2024.06.20D09:15:00.000000000 2
IBM    2024.06.20D09:30:00.000000000 2
IBM    2024.06.20D09:45:00.000000000 3

However it sounds like you're instead trying to have bucket-level lookbacks for all bucket levels. This could be done if you have all of the required data in memory
t:([]ticker:`g#9#`IBM;sourcetime:raze 2024.06.18D08:45 2024.06.18D09:00 2024.06.18D09:15+/:1D*til 3;data:1+til 9)
q)update ind101D:2 mavg data by ticker,`minute$sourcetime from t
ticker sourcetime                    data ind101D
-------------------------------------------------
IBM    2024.06.18D08:45:00.000000000 1    1
IBM    2024.06.18D09:00:00.000000000 2    2
IBM    2024.06.18D09:15:00.000000000 3    3
IBM    2024.06.19D08:45:00.000000000 4    2.5
IBM    2024.06.19D09:00:00.000000000 5    3.5
IBM    2024.06.19D09:15:00.000000000 6    4.5
IBM    2024.06.20D08:45:00.000000000 7    5.5
IBM    2024.06.20D09:00:00.000000000 8    6.5
IBM    2024.06.20D09:15:00.000000000 9    7.5

When it comes to days with early closing (fewer buckets) then you have to decide how to handle those. If there's no row in your table for that bucket then there will be no concept of the missing datapoint so the moving average (for example) will use a datapoint from a day earlier (aka a 10-day avg would actually span 11 trading days for that bucket if one of those days had missing buckets). To force it to use a 10 trading day span (9 actual trading days for that bucket) then you would have to add blank rows in your original table to represent the missing buckets. This also raises the question of what you fill the blank with - zero or null (generally nulls will be ignored in aggregations).
